# How do you choose between foam windscreen and/or a furry?

Tags: wind-protection, windjammer

Just wondering what the advantages and/or disadvantages are of using a regular foam windscreen and a furry together?

From the Rycote website I gather that adding a furry on top of a foam windscreen adds an extra amount of dBs in wind reduction.

Do you always start with a foam screen (for light to moderate wind) and add a furry for heavy wind?

Or are there any benefits to using just a furry without a foam screen underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rycote recommends that you do not put the foam on while inside your windshield as it actually decreases your wind protection.

Comment: Thanks Flipstar, this is the thing I was wondering about. Do you know the explanation of why this happens (adding foam decreasing wind protection)? 

Comment: My understanding is the whole point of the basket is to create an air pocket around the mic to buffer against wind. When you add the foam on your mic, you're essentially reducing the size of that air pocket with the foam.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the least amount of wind protection possible in a situation. The more you protect, the more you're blocking the sound you're recording as well.

Some of the Rycote wind shields are designed so that you can vary the level of wind protection using their own accessories. Thus, you can use what's ideal for a particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

I avoid using a furry when possible just because it's heavier (especially with a zeppelin). There is definitely a perceivable sonic difference as well. You lose some of the crispness of the dial w/ a big furry/zeppelin, though chances are that usage of NR or filtering in post (as is almost always done on exteriors) is going to eliminate that crispness anyways.